# Easiest way to restrict access to my jsonifier?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, security, permissions

I wrote a little method that takes a URL like:

```
/ajax/places/city?name__icontains=ranch
```

Then queries the `city` model for cities that have "ranch" in their name, and returns the results as json:

```
[
   {
      "pk":24944,
      "model":"places.city",
      "fields":{
         "province":1,
         "data_source":2,
         "elevation":null,
         "name":"108 Mile Ranch",
         "feature_class":null,
         "time_zone":null,
         "longitude":null,
         "feature_code":null,
         "mod_date":"2011-02-02 01:33:17",
         "latitude":null,
         "is_verified":true,
         "population":null
      }
   }, ...
```

This will be handy for my various auto-complete widgets.

Method looks like this:

```
def lookup(request, app_label, model_name):
    model = get_model(app_label, model_name)
    kwargs = dict((k,v) for k,v in request.GET.iteritems())
    objects = model.objects.filter(**kwargs)[:25]
    json = serializers.serialize('json', objects)
    return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/json')
```

Only problem is that it gives users unrestricted access to my database (they can type `/ajax/auth/user`).

I'm trying to figure out the easiest way to restrict it a bit. I can limit it to certain models for starters, but for things like Addresses, I need to use those in some autocompletes, but only users who own that Address should be able to see it.

I don't think the `request` object gets passed correctly (with the authenticated user) when the method is called via ajax, does it?

Does that mean I'd have to pass some kind of authentication key or session id along with each request? And even if I do get the logged-in user, I don't want to bake too much permission handling into that one method, I don't think it belongs there. Not sure how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 3):

This looks a lot like you're trying to allow arbitrary queries from the client side.

Don't. If you're writing all the queries, write them on the server side and create a separate method for each one of them. If users need to be able to write dynamic queries, come up with a (carefully restricted) method of your own instead of passing things directly to your model.

By the way, an "Ajax" request should be no different from a normal page load. If you use cookies for authentication, they should get passed just fine.

Comment: That's the way I usually do it. I have specific controller actions with predefined safe queries that I allow users to access. Which actions require authentication is also specified through the controller. Then the routing engine parses the request, and if the request ends in `.json`, the query results are rendered in a JSON view. Or if it's `.rss`, the results are rendered in an RSS view. Otherwise, it's rendered in the default HTML view. Some actions take parameters (like a search term, sort key, sort order, etc.), but no arbitrary queries.

Comment: Just trying to save myself some time when I start writing the Javascript portion of this code...don't like having to bake everything into the server side code and having all that duplication for each model, but I guess I don't have much of a choice. I think I'm going to build a sort of whitelist.

Answer (score 1):

Some type of authentication must be used, if you don't want it to be public. My API pages have something like this at the begining to ensure the user is logged in, and valid.

```
<?php
    require ('common.php'); //Validates users and populates the $me array using SESSION, and datastore

    if ( !$me['validLogin'] ) {
        die(json_encode(array(
            "status" => "ERR", 
            "message" => "Invalid Access"
        )));

    }
    //Do the rest of your API Magic here

?>
```

A token could be applicable, but you need to be careful that this token can't be grabbed from your javascript by someone who knows where to find it. That is why relying on your login architecture is a good solution.